# Package reference condition - exclude for some project

Tags: msbuild, conditional-statements, packagereference, itemgroup

I have the following entry in Package.props file on solution level:

```
<ItemGroup Label="My Label" Condition=" '$(SHFBSchemaVersion)' == '' ">
    <PackageReference Include="StyleCop.Analyzers">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>    
  </ItemGroup>
```

How should I edit this so that reference for StyleCop will be excluded for some project? Something like:

```
<ItemGroup Label="My Label" Condition=" '$(SHFBSchemaVersion)' == '' " Exclude="MyAwsomeProject">
```

So I would like that 'MyAwsomeProject' will not have a reference to StyleCop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working like this:

```
<ItemGroup Label="My Label" Condition=" '$(SHFBSchemaVersion)' == ''  And '$(AssemblyName)' != 'MyAwsomeProject'">
    <PackageReference Include="StyleCop.Analyzers">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>    
</ItemGroup>
```