# User-defined condition variable for package referencing in C# .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I have project reference in my csproj something like the following:

```
 <ItemGroup>
   <ProjectReference Include="..\..\test\PressurePointLib\PressurePointLib.csproj" />   
  </ItemGroup>
```

It is a library(DLL) that is only meant to be included within test environment and I don't want it to be linked to the current project in production.

I want this reference to be included conditionally based on condition variable.

I understand I can use condition references as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60852019/package-reference-condition-exclude-for-some-project) but I was wondering if I can define my own variable (say PressurePointsEnabled) and if so how do I set that build variable in command line and visual studio?

**UPDATE**
I tried the following and it looks like it worked.

```
 <ItemGroup Label="MyProject" Condition="'$(PressurePointsEnabled)'=='true'">
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\test\PressurePointLib\BlackLine.Test.PressurePointLib.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

and when I build

```
dotnet build -p:PressurePointsEnabled=true
```

How is that different @Berkay from your solution below, it looks more complex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay try this,

I have created a simple `console app` and `class library`, and used `dotnet` `build` from `powershell`.

Here is the csproj file,

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup Condition=" $(PressurePointsEnabled.Contains('PROD')) ">
        <ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="Test" AfterTargets="Build">
        <Message Text="Project $(ProjectName) Test PostBuild" Importance="high" />
        <Message Text="SUCCESS!" Condition=" $(PressurePointsEnabled.Contains('PROD')) " Importance="high" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

And as you said that I have used `PressurePointsEnabled`. After that I execute this command at `powershell`. I need to see **SUCCESS!** if condition is PROD otherwise post build event message won't be appear.

Here is the command;

```
dotnet build -p:PressurePointsEnabled="UAT" C:\Users\Berkay\source\repos\ConsoleApp4
```

The output:
[image]

And if I change it UAT to PROD, the output will be:

```
dotnet build -p:PressurePointsEnabled="UAT" C:\Users\Berkay\source\repos\ConsoleApp4
```

[image]

So, yes. You can define your own constant and set it's value, and check from `csproj`.

Comment: I tried something (added as UPDATE) above and it seems that it worked. Can you explain the difference between your solution and mine?

Comment: What do you mean by solution? Do you mean csproj file? I have pasted whole of it you just need the itemgroup and the condition part.

Comment: I meant your answer not "VS Solution". Look at my Update that's all I needed to do to make it work

Comment: Yes, my answer is kind of poc. Tried to explain and show the results of 2 different inputs. The single line works for you.

Comment: got it. Thanks a lot just making sure I am not missing anything crucial. :)

Comment: Thanks! How in the world did you find out about the "-p" option for "dotnet build"! The documentation does not show that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build  Is this an undocumented option?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my final solution in case anyone is curious:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(PressurePointsEnabled)'=='true'">
    <DefineConstants>PP_ENABLED</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

 

  <ItemGroup Label="PPLib" Condition="$(DefineConstants.Contains('PP_ENABLED'))"> 
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\test\PressurePointLib\MyService.Test.PressurePointLib.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

You can build with

```
dotnet build -p:PressurePointsEnabled=true
```

when that is true then PP_ENABLED is defined.

In the code you can use

```
#if PP_ENABLED
```

to define code that depends on the library included. Cheers.